# SharePoint 2013 Site Template Issue while creating new Site

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, site-template, site, web-template

I have created a Site Template using "Save Site as template" SharePoint option.
While creating a new site using the Custom Site Template facing the below issue.

[image]
Previously I was able to create the sites using custom templates.
Any Feedback's, Solutions welcomed. Thanks!

ULS Logs report:

> Failed to apply template "CMSPUBLISHING#0" to web at URL "http://sharepoint/ss", error The content type name '$Resources:ReportServerResources,DataSourceContentTypeName;' cannot contain: \  / : * ? " # % < > { } | ~ & , two consecutive periods (..), or special characters such as a tab. 0x1a1ac810

Comment: did you check the content type mentioned in the error having special character in it? alos check the ULS logs for exact name of content type

Comment: updated the ULS log above, let me know

Comment: Hi Hardik did you find any solution for it. I know its been very long but checking on as I am having the same trouble. Thanks